# getResourceAsStream() - InputStream null when using relative path

Tags: java, maven, junit, inputstream, relative-path

I am using Maven and running a JUnit test on a static method that tries to read in a file using:

```
InputStream is = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(filename);
```

And then using `new InputStreamReader(is)` to use as a reader in another call. This works when `filename` is just a filename (e.g. `file.csv`) but when `filename` is a relative path (e.g. `src/test/resources/file.csv`), `is` ends up being `null`.

I need it to handle relative paths, because I'm running a test suite via JUnit that looks for resources with relative paths and these tests are coming from a JAR that I have no control over changing (i.e. I implemented a facade implementation class that the test suite uses to call its own tests with its own resources - they are out of my control).

Is there a way for this approach to work with relative paths, or some other way that I can find those resources on my classpath that the tests are looking for?

Comment: Try removing src and starting with /test.

Comment: That was just a generic example. I won't be able to change the paths that get fed in because they are within a testing suite that I am unable to change. The hope is that the needed resources get put on my classpath and then the code will appropriately find them when creating the InputStream.

Comment: They will not be relative to my internal file system (which is why I can't use File and FileReader), they are relative paths defined in the JAR dependencies that Maven takes in.

Answer (score 2):

Running tests in maven, `src/test/resources/` is (by default) "mapped" to the **root** of the class(loader)path, so in your case `/file.csv` is the correct *absolute* path of `src/test/resources/file.csv`.

To load `"src/test/resources/file.csv"` (Resource) successfully (**which is comple nonsense**), you should have this file (physically) available: `src/test/resources/src/test/resources/file.csv`, or respectively `src/main/java`(which would also be mapped to cp root) ...`/src/test/resources/file.csv`

Comment: Putting the code in its own method won't fix anything. It's still just going to return null.

Answer (score 0):

In your case `is` ends up being null because when a resource lookup is performed, the `resources` directory is entry point, so the complete path is expected to be `test/resources/src/test/resources/file.csv` or `test/resources/src/test/resources/file.csv` depending on how you run your tests.

The only reliable way you could achieve your goal is to take care about the correctness manually. Perhaps something like this:

```
static String getResourceFileName(String maybePath) {
    Path path = Paths.get(maybePath);
    if (path.getNameCount() > 0) {
        return path.getFileName().toString();
    } else {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Can't derive filename given " + maybePath);
    }
}

@Test
public void testSoq() throws Exception {
    String fileName0 = getResourceFileName("file");
    InputStream is0 = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(fileName0);

    String fileName1 = getResourceFileName("src/test/resources/file");
    InputStream is1 = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(fileName1);
    String string0 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is0)).readLine();
    String string1 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is1)).readLine();
    assertEquals(string0, string1); // OK
}
```

Maybe you'll have to write it according to the specifics of your case (account for possible nested diretories etc.), but I really think that given your inputs may be of arbitrary nature, this won't get much simpler.

Answer (score 0):

I have this on blog (in spanish)

http://lacuevadeyogui.blogspot.com/2015/04/diferencia-entre-uri-y-url.html

The problem in with the reference to file in src/test/resources

try this

```
URL url = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("file.csv");
File f;
try {
    f = new File(url.toURI());
} catch (URISyntaxException e) {
    f = new File(url.getPath());
}
```

At the end, convert file to inputStream.